# Track Event requests go to Azure App Insights and receives a CORS error

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, azure-application-insights

I experience a problem when I try to utilize Application Insight for my javascript application. 
Getting the following error on my browser’s console logs when I attempted to use Application Insight deployed on Microsoft Azure platform;

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track.Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the equest's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'domain' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have configured CORS access via Azure Insights.

- Allowed Origin: My domain.
- Allowed Methods: GET/PUT
- Allowed Headers: x-ms-blob-type, x-ms-blob-content-type,
  content-length, and accept
- Exposed Headers: none (i.e. leave it blank) Max Age in Seconds: 8600
  (i.e. 1 hour)

Track Event (X) requests go to Azure App Insights and receives a CORS error. We are developing using NODE.js, compile with browserify tool and run it in browser.I’m trying to make a CORS post request, and I got it working in plain javascript like this:

app.js

```
var AppInsights = require("applicationinsights");  

AppInsights.setup("KEY XXX").start();
```

config.js

```
events: {  pre_login_loaded: "pre_login_anonymous_loaded-01",
```

LoginPage.js

```
var appInsights = APP.appInsights; 
// When anonymous is entered
function setupWelcomePage() {
appInsights.trackEvent(config.analitics.events.pre_login_anonymous_loaded)
```

Could you please help me on this topic. I appreciate any help that may guide me to the right direction to figure out the cause of the problem.
Thanks,

Comment: I am wondering where did you configure CORS?

Comment: i set it through Azure Portal/Cors section

Comment: Managed to solve this? For me just loading plain javascript code